# Collections.sort() leaves my list unsorted

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` of `PostingsEntry` objects according to the `score` attribute of the `PostingsEntry` objects. The list resides in a `PostingsList` object that has the `sort()` method.

```
public class PostingsEntry implements Comparable<PostingsEntry>{

    public int docID;
    public double score = 0;
    private TreeSet<Integer> positions = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    /** 
     *  PostingsEntries are compared by their score (only relevant
     *  in ranked retrieval).
     *
     *  The comparison is defined so that entries will be put in 
     *  descending order.
     */

    public int compareTo( PostingsEntry other ) { 
        return Double.compare( other.score, score );
    } 
}

public class PostingsList{

    private int position = 0;
    /** The postings list */
    private ArrayList<PostingsEntry> list = new ArrayList<PostingsEntry>();

    private class PostingsEntryComparator implements Comparator<PostingsEntry>{
        @Override
        public int compare(PostingsEntry pA, PostingsEntry pB){
            return pA.docID - pB.docID;
        }   
    }   
    /** Number of postings in this list. */
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }   

    /** Returns the ith posting. */
    public PostingsEntry get( int i ) { 
    return list.get( i );
    }      

    public void sort(){
        Collections.sort(list, new PostingsEntryComparator());
    }   

}
```

I'm trying to sort the list here:

```
// sort postingsList
postingsList.sort();
```

And I print the results:

```
for(int i=0; i<postingsList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(index.docNames.get(postingsList.get(i).docID));
    System.out.printf("score: %f\n\n", postingsList.get(i).score);
}
```

But I get:

```
davisWiki/Zombie_Attack_Response_Guide.f
score: 0,019064

davisWiki/EvanGray.f
score: 0,004368

davisWiki/Mortal_Forever.f
score: 0,002708

davisWiki/JasonRifkind.f
score: 0,767518

davisWiki/Measure_Z.f
score: 0,031980
```

Which shows that the list has clearly not been sorted. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your call of `sort` passes a different comparator:

```
public void sort(){
    Collections.sort(list, new PostingsEntryComparator());
}
```

For the purpose of this sort, this `PostingsEntryComparator` replaces the "natural order" by `score`, as established by `PostingsEntry`'s implementation of `Comparable<PostingsEntry>`. Hence, the entries are compared on their `docID`. If you print `docID` in place of `score`, you will see that your list is properly ordered according to IDs.

**Note:** Subtracting IDs of two items being compared could produce incorrect results due to integer overflow. Use [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) instead, in the same way that you correctly used `Double.compare` in `PostingsEntry.compareTo`.

Answer (score 7):

When you call

```
 Collections.sort(list, new PostingsEntryComparator());
```

you are sorting by `PostingsEntryComparator`, which compares the `docID`s.

If you want to sort by score, you need to use the `Comparable` implementation of your `PostingsEntry`, which you can do by calling `Collections.sort()` without passing a `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```